# Javascripting for Adobe Illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to produce a script that will:

1. comb through all the layers and sublayers in a file
2. then flatten each layer that DOES NOT have a layer inside of it.
3. take the flattened layers and gets their POSITION RELATIVE to an
   item with a name containing the word "area" that resides in the
   flattened layers' parent layer,
4. combs through all layers and finds all sibling layers or sublayers,
   and gets their POSITION RELATIVE to each other in order from the top
   down,
5. assigns a variable to each value,
6. then applies each value varioius mathematical formulas,
7. takes the results of those formulas and exports the data to a
   different text file and changes the extension to a word I would
   define,
8. creates a list of all layers and sublayers and organizes the list
   as an xml document with a nested structure based on the nested
   structure of the layers and change the extension to a second word I
   would define,
   THEN
9. selects certain layers based on whether or not that layer or
   sublayer has a name containing a currently undefined word or phrase
   like "column" and copies these layers to new documents,
10. repositions certain layers within the new documents based on
    whether or not that layer or sublayer has a name containing a
    currently undefined word or phrase like "top-left",
11. selects certain layers based on whether or not that layer or
    sublayer has a name containing a currently undefined word or phrase
    like "top" and flattens them together,
12. and exports them to a .png file, a .gif file, and a .jpg2

Comment: And which part of that script do you need help with?

Comment: Holy stream of consciousness...

Comment: Great! Post the result here when you're done, I'm sure others will profit from it.

Comment: -Brandon.
All of it, I'm brand new.

Comment: I've found alot of scripts that I thought I could modify to do this, but they all seem not to work when it comes to nested layers.

Answer (score 0):

ExtendScript
http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=111&platform=windows